# Functions arugments ... in C

Tags: c, function, arguments

```
void foo(const gchar *a, ...)
{
    do_something();
}
```

What does the `...` mean?

Does it only work with glib?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

Comment: @Mysticial I just don't know how to name it. Thanks!

Comment: See [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section 7.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [variable-length argument list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html) which allows a function to have flexible number of arguments. It's part of the Standard. So it works everywhere that standard C is supported (or this feature itself is supported), not just glib.